# How to replace missing key/value with zero using slice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a hash. I need to extract some key/value pairs, but some desired keys are missing.

How can I replace the missing pairs with `"key" => 0.0` when I call `attributes.slice` on the record and keys as follows:

```
record = Model.last
record.attributes.slice('k1','k2','k3','k4','k5') # this returns
=> {"k1"=> 343, k3=> 0.0}
```

If some keys are missing then they won't appear in the result. How can I get the remaining missing keys assigned with `0.0`?

Answer (score 5):

Suppose

```
h = { 'k2'=>2, 'k1'=>1 }
```

and

```
all_keys = ['k1', 'k2', 'k3', 'k4']
```

then

```
all_keys.map { |k| h.fetch(k,0.0) }
  #=> [1, 2, 0.0, 0.0]
```

See [Hash#fetch](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch).

Comment: Nicer 'n mine. :-)

Comment: How can I get   `#=> ['k1'=>1, 'k2'=>2, 'k3'=>0.0, 'k4' => 0.0]`

Comment: One way: `all_keys.each_with_object({}) { |k,g| g[k] = h.fetch(k,0.0) } #=> { 'k1'=>1, 'k2'=>2, 'k3'=>0.0, 'k4'=>0.0 }`.

Answer (score 1):

We can take advantage of the fact that a hash can be overwritten with new key/value pairs:

```
{a: 0, b: 0}.merge(a: 2) # => {:a=>2, :b=>0}
```

Knowing that, we can do something like this:

```
desired_keys = [:a, :b]
foo = {a: 1}

desired_keys.zip([0] * desired_keys.size).to_h.merge(foo.slice(*desired_keys))
 # => {:a=>1, :b=>0}
```

`desired_keys` is a predefined list of the key/value pairs we want, `foo` is the actual hash the real values are coming from.

`[0] * 2 # => [0, 0]` creates an array of a given size.

`desired_keys.zip([0] * desired_keys.size).to_h` creates a temporary hash of the values being used as filler.

`merge(foo.slice(*desired_keys))` grabs the pairs we wanted. In this situation, `*` AKA "splat" explodes the array into its individual elements, so they're passed as separate parameters to `slice`. Here's what's happening:

```
def bar(*a)
  a
end

bar(%w[a b]) # => [["a", "b"]]
bar(*%w[a b]) # => ["a", "b"]
```

Notice that the first call is passing in an array, whereas the second passes separate values.

Breaking it down a little to make it a bit more apparent:

```
desired_keys.zip([0] * desired_keys.size).to_h # => {:a=>0, :b=>0}
            .merge(foo.slice(*desired_keys))   # => {:a=>1, :b=>0}
```

Because we know the record fields we're retrieving, it's easy to create that temporary hash once, in advance, then reuse it every time, resulting in very fast code:

```
DESIRED_KEYS = [:a, :b]
ZERO_HASH = DESIRED_KEYS.zip([0] * DESIRED_KEYS.size).to_h # => {:a=>0, :b=>0}

foo = {a: 1}

ZERO_HASH.merge(foo.slice(*DESIRED_KEYS))
# => {:a=>1, :b=>0}
```

All the methods, including [`*`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-2A) are part of [Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html) or [Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Hash.html).

How to use `0.0` instead of `0` is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score -1):

I think this should work in your case

```
Model.slice('k1','k2','k3','k4','k5').transform_values! { |v| v ? v : 0.0 }
```

Comment: This won't work. The values you seek to transform to "0.0" don't exist in the sliced hash, because the keys don't exist.